# cannot display preference Activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

i am trying to create a prefrence acivity but it does not work .i don´t know if the isue is on the method   "addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencia);" which is depracated .

EDIT:i was declaring at the manifest the wrong name .i was declaring preferencia.xml instead of the prefres.java.

the main Activity:

```
public class Asteroides extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MediaPlayer player;
    private Button boton1;
    private Button boton2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        boton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
             player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);

             player.start();    

        }
    }


     @Override
     protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

                player.stop();
               if (isFinishing()){
               player.stop();
               player.release();
                }

        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.asteroides, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void play(View v ){
          Intent i = new Intent(Asteroides.this,prefers.class);
            startActivity(i);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.conf:
            startActivity(new Intent(Asteroides.this, 
                   prefers.class));


            return true;
        case R.id.about:
            startActivity(new Intent(Asteroides.this, 
                   MainActivity.class));


            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }


    }

}
```

the main xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="uf3.asteroides.Asteroides"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="203dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:text="@string/asteroid"
            android:textColor="#CC0000"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/play"
            android:onClick="play"
            android:text="@string/jugar"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/p"
            android:text="@string/puntuacion"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

prefers.java

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

    public class prefers extends PreferenceActivity{

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencia);
        }



    }
```

prefrencia.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <PreferenceCategory android:title="Category1" >
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="checkboxPref"
                android:summary="True or False"
                android:title="Checkbox" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="Category2" >
            <EditTextPreference
                android:defaultValue="[Introduce un string aqui]"
                android:key="EditTextPref"
                android:summary="Introduce un String"
                android:title="EditText" />

            <RingtonePreference
                android:key="ringtonePref"
                android:summary="Selecciona un Tono"
                android:title="RingTones" />

            <PreferenceScreen
                android:key="secondPrefScreenPref"
                android:summary="Pulse aquí para ir a la segunda pantalla de Preferencias"
                android:title="Segunda Pantalla Preferencias" >
                <EditTextPreference
                    android:key="secondEditTextPref"
                    android:summary="Introduce un String"
                    android:title="EditText (Segunda Pantalla)" />
            </PreferenceScreen>
        </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceScreen>
```

the menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="uf3.asteroides.Asteroides" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/conf"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Configuración"
        android:icon="@drawable/set"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />

     <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="A cerca de..."
        android:icon="@drawable/ic"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>


</menu>
```

the logcat:

```
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095): Process: uf3.asteroides, PID: 2095
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     ... 11 more
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {uf3.asteroides/uf3.asteroides.prefers}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     at uf3.asteroides.Asteroides.play(Asteroides.java:68)
05-03 17:23:50.076: E/AndroidRuntime(2095):     ... 14 more
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uf3.asteroides"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="uf3.asteroides.Asteroides"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="uf3.asteroides.preferencia" />
        <activity
            android:name="uf3.asteroides.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="uf3.asteroides.Puntuaciones"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_puntuaciones" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Any errors in the logcat?

Comment: unfortunately ,Asteroides has stopped.

Comment: that is the message that is displayed to the user. I meant what is in the _logcat_?

Comment: ah ok,i've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this line in the logcat:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {uf3.asteroides/uf3.asteroides.prefers}; 
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

==> Seems like your forgot to declare the PreferenceActivity in your AndroidManifest.

Comment: i think is already declared .can you take a look at the manifest please!.

Comment: You put `android:name="uf3.asteroides.preferencia"` but that is the name of the xml! You need to put the name of the Activity class `android:name="uf3.asteroides.prefers"` (like you did it with the other activities) BTW: I would rename the Activity, so that it starts with Uppercase letters, like the other activities.

Comment: Cool, you may want to click the ✔-icon next to this answer then ;-)